# PHP Variable's value is 0 after assigning a date in function

Tags: php, mysql, class, date

I have a function that is part of a class or library that will send a user's birthdate to a database. For some reason the variable that holds that information `($this->birthdate)` is sending a value of 0000-00-00 instead of the actual birthdate.

Here is my sample code:

```
function isAgeValid(){

     $birthDate1=$this->birth_year.'-'.$this->birth_month.'-'.$this->birth_day;
     $birthDate1 = explode("-", $birthDate1);
     $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate1[0], $birthDate1[1], $birthDate1[2]))) > date("md")
            ? ((date("Y")-$birthDate1[2])-1):(date("Y")-$birthDate1[2]));
    $this->birthdate=($birthDate1);

    return ($age > 17);
}
```

Comment: Don't assume your code is correct, always var_dump() results to confirm your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$birthDate1=$this->birth_year.'-'.$this->birth_month.'-'.$this->birth_day;
 $birthDate1 = explode("-", $birthDate1);
```

This is just pointless and my guess is that second line causes Your problem.
Later You have

```
$this->birthdate=($birthDate1);
```

so birthday has an array not a string with date.

Comment: You concatenate 3 variables and later use explode to put them into array, if You need them in array just write `$birthDate1 = array($this->birth_year, $this->birth_month, $this->birth_day)`

Comment: I see your point. What I have done to resolve the issue by placing $this->birthdate under the 1st line of code in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to change the field in the database to type [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) and save it to the database as a [Unix Timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). If you need to pull the human-readable date from the timestamp again, use `$birthdate = date("Y-m-d",$timestamp);`

```
$birthdate = strtotime($this->birth_year." ".$this->$birth_month." ".$this->birth_day
if($birthdate !== false)){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(timestamp_field)VALUES('".$birthdate."')");
}
```

This also protects against [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as the strtotime function ensures $birthdate is a number.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter/cleaner:

```
function isAgeValid() {
    $this->birthdate = $this->birth_year . '-' . $this->birth_month . '-' . $this->birth_day;
    $age = date('Y') - $this->birth_day - (date("md", strtotime($this->birthdate)) > date("md") ? 1 : 0);
    return ($age > 17);
}
```